# WordPress - Add rewrite rule for plugin output URL

Tags: wordpress

I want to redirect this URL: `http://example.com/?login=true` to `http://example.com/login/true`.

I add this hook to `fuctions.php` but not work. Is anyway?

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^login/true/$', 'index.php?login=true' ,'top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: Have you flushed the rewrite rules - just visit the permalinks setting admin page. And looking at your RegEx, you should make the ending `/` be optional: `^login/true/?$`

Comment: @SallyCJ yes. I do that. but not work

Comment: @SallyCJ Why your answers are cleared?

Comment: Well, let's just ignore that answer, ok? :) So, did you follow my suggestion on using the Redirection plugin? Is everything ok now?

Comment: i did not test your suggestion :-/

Comment: Ok I can undelete the answer, but do you still need help with this?